# Detect the white background license plate region using opencv(Edge Detection, Contour Detection)

Tags: python, opencv, contour, edge-detection, automatic-license-plate-recognition

I want to detect the white number plate region using contour detection and edge detection using opencv[image]

I have tried a variety of solutions. These work for sharp images but don't work for low res images and images that are not sharp enough.

```
import cv2 as cv2
import numpy as np

# ------------------------Preprocessing Start----------------------------------------
# Read the image file
image = cv2.imread(
    'nepali-dataset/IMG_0124.jpg')


# Convert to Grayscale Image
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow("Before denoising", gray_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

gray_image = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(gray_image, None, 20, 7, 21)
cv2.imshow("After denoising", gray_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)


# # # Canny Edge Detection
canny_edge = cv2.Canny(gray_image, 170, 200)
cv2.imshow("Traditional canny_edge detect", canny_edge)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# morphological operations

kernel = np.ones((5, 15), np.uint8)

canny_edge = cv2.dilate(canny_edge, None)
cv2.imshow("dilate", canny_edge)
cv2.waitKey(0)

canny_edge = cv2.erode(canny_edge, None)
cv2.imshow("Erode", canny_edge)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# -------------------------Preprocessing End---------------------------------------

# -------------------------Candidate area detection Start---------------------------------------
# Find contours based on Edges
contours, new = cv2.findContours(
    canny_edge.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[:30]

# Initialize license Plate contour and x,y coordinates
contour_with_license_plate = None
license_plate = None
x = None
y = None
w = None
h = None

# Find the contour with 4 potential corners and creat ROI around it
for contour in contours:
    # Find Perimeter of contour and it should be a closed contour
    perimeter = cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, 0.01 * perimeter, True)
    if len(approx) == 4:  # see whether it is a Rect
        print("Got ctr")
        contour_with_license_plate = approx
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        license_plate = gray_image[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        image = cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 10)

# # Removing Noise from the detected image, before sending to Tesseract
# license_plate = cv2.bilateralFilter(license_plate, 11, 17, 17)
# (thresh, license_plate) = cv2.threshold(license_plate, 150, 180, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)


# image = cv2.rectangle(image, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), 10)
image = cv2.resize(image, (600, 600))
cv2.imshow("License Plate Detection", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
# ---------------------Candidate area detection End-------------------------------------------
```

Is there any way to detect white background rectangles or someway else to detect it?

Comment: There are no white numbers. Only the red numbers that you posted on OP.

Comment: what's the significance of `type he` before your import statements?

Comment: ALPR is done using AI, specifically convolutional neural networks

Comment: Show a low res license that does not work!  How poor is it?

Comment: I would like to provide a little advice on your wording.  Your task is to "detect the white number plate".  Using OpenCV contour and edge detection is just one possible path to achieve that task.  It is not part of your task.